# Extracting inter-event waiting time distribution and testing whether its exponentially distributed

Tags: r, time-series

Is there any way that I can apply hazard/survival analysis to functions of a time series?
Here is an example. This is the simple expected shortfall with alpha=.95 of time SP500 time series with rolling window of length 500.

```
library(zoo)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(rugarch)
data(sp500ret)
rollES95=rollapplyr(as.ts(sp500ret), 500, function(u) (ES(u, p=.95)))
```

I want to find the out whether or not the inter-event distribution between -100*rollES95 with threshold 3.5 is exponentially or non-exponentially distributed. I expect a rejection of the null hypothesis of exponentially distributed (iid occurrence of -100*rollES95> 3.5).

Comment: I hate when people ask about something between one number.

Comment: How about `qqplot` ?  Generate your expected normal dist w/ desired mu and sigma, and `qqplot` it against your data set.